# Can't assign to struct without explicit type specification

Tags: c, struct

With this definition

```c
struct A {
    int x;
};
```

why is

```c
struct A a = {0};
```

valid syntax while

```c
struct A a;

a = {0};
```

produces the error, "expected expression before '{' token"?

If I replace that line with

```c
a = (struct A){0};
```

then everything is fine so it's not a problem with assigning to structures.

Comment: Nitpick, it's not a cast. It's a [compound literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/compound_literal).

Comment: I don't have the corresponding standard in hand, but one is the initialization syntax, the other would need to be an 'assignment syntax', which is not declared for structs. I imagine the compiler turns the latter into 'Construction of a variable of type A using the initialization syntax, which is then copied to a', although I cannot say for certain.

Comment: @RefugnicEternium: The grammar for assignments is the same for structures as it is for other objects. `a = {0};` does not work because `{0}` does not denote a structure value, not because structures cannot be assigned to.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What I meant to say is, that you can only assign structs (of the same type) to structs, but not initializer lists. My apologies if I failed to express myself properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The curly brace syntax `{}` designates an initializer list, and such a list can only be used in an initialization.

In this case:

```
struct A a = {0};
```

`a` is being declared and initialized with `{0}` and is valid syntax.

This is not valid:

```
a = {0};
```

Because this is an expression an initializer list can't appear in an expression.

This:

```
a = (struct A){0};
```

Is not a cast but an example of a *compound literal*.  The syntax is similar to that of a cast, but what it is doing instead is creating an object of type `struct A` and giving an initializer for it.  This object is then assigned to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can only use initializers in a declaration, so statement `a = {0};` is invalid.

In statement `a = (struct A){0};` you are actually assigning using a compound literal expression, which is valid.